# Make the distance of a UIView to its super view proportional

Tags: ios, uiview

You see the orange part is a UIView, the white part is also an UIView. The orange view is the super view of white view.

I have defined the constraint for the white view to have "Bottom Space to super view **140**", and "Top Space to super view **219**", which looks like this in iPhone7:

[image]

If I switch to smaller screen, e.g. iPhone 4, it would look like the following:

[image]

As you see, the white area in smaller screen become smaller.

I would like to ask how to make the white area occupy the same percentage of area of the device screen that the area ratio doesn't change? (I mean how to make the top & bottom distance of white view proportional to the super view, not like what I did fixed space to bottom and top which produces the problem)

**===== UPDATE ====**

I followed @Phillip Mills's simple answer, managed to make the white area's **height** proportional to super view, however, I got a new issue that xcode complains about the **Y positioning** of the white area. Again, how to make the **Y positioning** proportional as well like the **height**?

Comment: It is not duplicated, because the answer in the linked post says something like " Editor -> Pin -> Widths Equally" but I can't find it in xcode8

Answer (score 0):

Use a constraint that makes the subview height equal to the parent view's height.  Then change the multiplier in the constraint to a float value less than 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK, thanks, it works like you suggested, but that only defines the height of white area is proportional to super view, I still need to define the Y position of the height? How to define Y position proportional as well?

Comment: @Leem.fin You can do essentially the same thing with a centering constraint  between the two views, adjusting a multiplier to position whatever amount off-center you like.

Comment: is it a centering vertical or horizontal constraint in my case?

Comment: Vertical for y.

Comment: Thanks @Phillip Mills, do you know what should I search for tutorial on this kind of proportional to super view thing? I would like to have a concrete learning on it.

Comment: it works in xcode device view, but when run on emulater, doing what you mentioned makes the white area disappear from the screen.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you.  I just updated my answer with pictures of a pair of examples that work fine for me here in simulators.  (Xcode has a Debug View Hierarchy option that let's you examine views at runtime.  Maybe that will point out something wrong about constraints, size, z-order....)